# Javascript: parsing negative Number(hexadecimal | binary)

Tags: javascript, numbers

It works with a lot number types, but not with negatives hexadecimal or binary.
Too, `Number(octal)` doesn't parse an octal number.

```
Number("15")    ===   15;  // OK
Number("-15")   ===  -15;  // OK
Number("0x10")  ===   16;  // OK
Number("0b10")  ===    2;  // OK
Number("-0x10") ===  NaN;  // FAIL (expect  -16)
Number("-0b10") ===  NaN;  // FAIL (expect   -2)
Number("0777")  ===  777;  // FAIL (expect  511)
Number("-0777") === -777;  // FAIL (expect -511)
```

**Question**: how I can parse all valid Javascript numbers correctly?

**Edit A**

`parseInt()` don't help me because I need check by each possibility (if start with `0x` I use `16`, for instance).

**Edit B**

If I write on Chrome console `0777` it turns to `511`, and too allow negative values. Even works if I write directly into javascript code. So I expect basically a parser that works like javascript parser. But I think that the negative hexadecimal, for instance, on really is `0 - Number(hex)` in the parser, and not literraly `Number(-hex)`. But octal values make not sense.

Comment: You could easily create your own function which inspects the first three characters of the string and handles it accordingly.

Comment: `parseInt()` with the matching radix seems to work.

Comment: `parseInt("-0x10",16)` gives you `-16`, and `parseInt("-0777",8)` gives you `-511`

Comment: Note that some implementations of Javascript consider a leading `0` to indicate octal, but that's not ECMAScript 5 specifies. It specifies that it should be treated as decimal, which is what `Number` is doing in your example with `Number("0777")`. Since it's browser dependent, you really should decide on your own rules for how numbers will be handled and implement that with `parseInt` specifying the desired radix.

Comment: [Binary, octal, and hexidecimal literals](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-literals-numeric-literals) have not been defined to support signs. Only a *DecimalLiteral* includes the syntax for *SignedInteger*.

Comment: @Jonathan: Which is still surprising though, isn't it? I wasn't aware of that, it seems kind of arbitrary.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah. I can only guess it was decided for the sake of the parser. But, it appears to be from JavaScript's early days as [ES1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) lists hex and octal literals the same way.

Comment: `If I write on Chrome console 0777 it turns to 511` but that's a literal number, you are trying to parse a string. Those are two different things.

Comment: Regarding "Edit B:" Octal literals have changed in ES6 to `0o[0-7]+`. The now "legacy" syntax of `0[0-7]+` only continues to be available when strict mode is *not* used.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

parseInt(string, base):

```
parseInt("-0777", 8) 
parseInt("-0x10", 16)
```

Comment: I guess the issue is that the base is not known beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function to handle the negative value.

```
function parseNumber (num) {
   var neg = num.search('-') > -1;
   var num = Number(num.replace('-', ''));
   return num * (neg ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not parsing octal and the other examples because they're not valid Javascript numbers, at least within the constraints of `Number`. So the technically correct answer is: use `Number`!

If you want to parse other formats, then you can use `parseInt`, but you will have to provide the base.

Comment: *"because they're not valid Javascript numbers"*: Why is `-0x10` not a valid number?

Comment: It's not valid within the constraints of `Number`. As a way-out example, π² is a valid number, but not within `Number`, or within Javascript!

Comment: If you refer to the algorithm that converts strings to numbers (which is different from the `Number` function!) (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1), then I agree. When I said "valid number" I was meaning within JavaScript. So yes, `π²` is not a valid number but `-0x10` is: `console.log(-0x10);` (though technically `0x10` is the number `-` is the unary minus operator). The point is that this character sequence is valid in JS source.

Answer (score 0):

This gets a little ugly, but you could inspect the values to determine the right radix for `parseInt`. In particular, the `b` for binary doesn't seem to be support by my browser (Chrome) at all, so unlike the OP, `Number("0b10")` gives me `NaN`. So you need to remove the `b` for it to work at all.

```js
var numbers = [
  "15", "-15", "0x10", "0b10", "-0x10", "-0b10", "0777", "-0777"
];

function parser(val) {
  if (val.indexOf("x") > 0) {
    // if we see an x we assume it's hex
    return parseInt(val, 16);
  } else if (val.indexOf("b") > 0) {
    // if we see a b we assume it's binary
    return parseInt(val.replace("b",""),2);
  } else if (val[0] === "0") {
    // if it has a leading 0, assume it's octal
    return parseInt(val, 8);
  }
  // anything else, we assume is decimal
  return parseInt(val, 10);
}

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  console.log(parser(numbers[i]));
}
```

Note this obviously isn't foolproof (for example, I'm checking for `x` but not `X`), but you can make it more robust if you need to.